# Cannot build after upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 / TACO Update 8

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-cordova, taco

Today I upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 including TACO Update 8. When I try to build, it fails. In the detailed error log, I see (beside others):

> Installing npm 2.14.9. This could take a few minutes... Failed : The
>   remote server returned an error : (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

I assume this happens since TACO is now detecting the proxy by itself, but for the credentials this is not possible. Therefore I disabled the automatic proxy detection as well as the sandboxed version of NodeJS. Additionally I cleared the Cordova cache.

But the build is still failing. The strange thing is it is still trying to install npm 2.14.9. I get now:

> Failed: The specified path, file name, or bot are too long. The fully qualified name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters,

I assume this happens my %APPDATA% directory is part of a roaming profile placed on a network share. Therefore the content of the APPDATA variable has a length of 82 characters.

Therefore I am using with npm in general the prefix c:\npm, which is working perfect. But unfortunately, TACO ignores it...

So my questions are:

- Can I specify the NPM prefix also for TACO?
- Can I avoid to install NPM 2.14.9 (which was my expected behaviour after un-checking the 2 options)?

And finally:

- It would be great if I could enter also the proxy credentials somewhere.

Comment: I think it tries to install the NPM is because Visual Studio is trying to use a sandboxed version of NodeJS to avoid version conflict issues. Go to the setting window where you clear the Cordova Cache, there is a check box "Use a sandboxed version of NodeJS". Uncheck it and see if you can start to build your code. Also try to add your npm path to system Path environment variables. It's only a workaround. I will check with VS team to see if there is any option to make it easy to configure.

Comment: I am running into the same issue, unchecking the box does not fix the issue.

Comment: Clarification: Unchecking the "Use a sandboxed version of NodeJS" box does not fix the issue. It still tries to install NPM 2.14.9

Comment: I have the same problem.  What I can't understand is that my global npm version is 2.14.9 and yet it still tries to install it.  It doesn't matter if the sandbox checkbox is ticked or not.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to be a general problem with NodeJS 2.14.9 on Windows.  I believe the issues has been resolved in later versions of NodeJS, so now the question is how to get VS to try and install a different version for the sandbox, seeing that the sandbox checkbox doesn't work.  I found places where the sandboxNpmVersion is set, but even changing that doesn't work.  It is here:

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-tac\install.js(22):var sandboxNpmVersion = '2.14.9';
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\Packages\vs-tac\lib\util.js(25):var sandboxNpmVersion = '2.14.9';

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: YES!!  I finally found the solution.  Turns out the path that was causing the issue was in"C:\Users\my_very_very_very_very_long_username\AppData"

Answer (score 0):

YES!!  I finally found the solution.  Turns out the path that was causing the issue was in:
"C:\Users\my_very_very_very_very_long_username\AppData"

So I fixed it by moving my AppData folder according to this article:
http://www.tweaklibrary.com/System/Application-Path/71/Change-default-location-of-the-%E2%80%9CApplication-Data%E2%80%9D-folder/10471/

Rebooted and after that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the setting window where you clear the Cordova Cache, there is a check box "Use a sandboxed version of NodeJS". Uncheck it and see if you can start to build your code. Also try to add your npm path to system Path environment variables. It's only a workaround.